# Issue reading a file path from a Properties file

Tags: java, properties

I'm working on a swing app that will allow users to view sets of (mostly locally-stored) files. I'm able to store lists of files (among other preferences) as text in Properties files but when I try to pull file values back out, using

`myProperties.getProperty("File")`

it discards *some* of the '\'s that are in the text. I confirmed that writing to the Properties files like this:

`myPrintWriter.println("File = " + myFile.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "/"))`

or this:

`myPrintWriter.println("File = " + myFile.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\"))`

would allow `getProperty()` to work more like I expected but I didn't like having to convert my data to a Java-specific format without an explanation in the API so I decided to write it up on Stack Overflow.

---

But when I got to this point in my post started feeling embarrassed; I was about to post on Stack Overflow without even consulting the Java source code for `java.util.Properties` (distributed with the JDK). I found that the Javadoc comments for `Properties.load()` indicate this was a design decision which, for example, allows Properties values to contain line breaks. I guess I'll look into writing my Properties files in XML if I find that I need that language-independence.

---

Epilogue: So this is my first post on Stack Overflow and I've answered my own question but I've decided to post it anyhow in the hopes some person (or, perhaps, some artificial natural-language-processing-intelligence) may find it useful (or illuminating). Also, I'm curious as to any ideas or suggestions people might post in reply. TL;DR? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Properties.store()` to write out your properties. `store()` is documented as writing properties in a format that `load()` will read, so it will take care of any massaging that needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's more like what I was looking for! There's only ~15 methods specific to Properties, I really should have read through the method names/signatures...

Answer (score 2):

If applicable, you can use double backslashes - `c:\\test\\test.txt`:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("test", "c:\\test\\test.txt");
System.out.println(props.getProperty("test"));
```

On Windows system you can also use forward slashes - `c:/test/test.txt`:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("test", "c:/test/test.txt");
System.out.println(props.getProperty("test"));
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I decided to do. As I mentioned in my post, this behavior is explained in the Javadoc for the Properties class (not in getProperty() but "upstream" in load()).